# django-restframework serialize relations as dictionaries rather then arrays

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize foreign keys as dictionaries instead of arrays.
Right now the json looks the following:

```
{
"slug": "en",
"children": [{
        "slug": "pants",
        "children": [{
                "slug": "products/:level1",
                "children": [{
                    "slug": ":level2/:level3",
                    "children": []
                }]
            },
            {
                "slug": ":productSlug",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "slug": "pullovers",
        "children": []
    }
   ]
}
```

But I'd like it to use the slugs as keys:

```
{
"en": {
    "children": {
        "pants": {
            "children": {
                "products/:level1": {
                    "children": {
                        ":level2/:level3": {
                            "children": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            ":productSlug": {
                "children": {}
            }
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

Is it possible to do that directly in the serializer or do I have to convert it in an additional step?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by overriding the [list serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) and setting `list_serializer_class` for each serializer that requires it, as I suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31606185/4797469).

Of course, you will need to adapt it slightly:

```
class <YourClass>ListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        r = super().to_representation(data)

        return { item['<key_field>']: item for item in r }
```

Comment: Nice answer. I had to tweak it a little, so I was able to use it for the top level as well. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Rigonis answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238191/270265) was the key to success. I had to tweak it a little, so I was able to use it for the top level as well.:

```
class DictSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    key = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key = kwargs.pop('key', self.key)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, data):    
        r = super().to_representation(data)
        return {item[self.key]: item for item in r}

    @property
    def data(self):
        # This is a bit nasty, because the only "Many-Serializer" is a ListSerializer we inherit of it,
        # but when converting it to json we call the BaseSerializer directly, because we want a Dictionary rather then a list
        ret = super(serializers.ListSerializer, self).data
        return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
```

Comment: Looking at DRF code, it indeed seems necessary to use `ReturnDict` in `data`.